# How to redirect to an MVC view from AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I need to redirect to another MVC view from a controller in AngularJS. Which services do I need to inject? I tried $window service
and it does not work. Do I have to use $http service?
Does anyone have any example for this? Thank you!

AngularJS controller:

```
$window.location('/Home/Index');
```

MVC controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Giude - Using `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

location is not an method over `window` object. Simply assign URL to location `property`

```
 $window.location = '/Home/Index';
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try with full path in location

```
var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/Home/Index";
$window.location.href = url;
```